# viewDidLoad not called even though ViewController deinit was called after user force quit app

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    deinit {
        print("VC: deinit")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("VC: viewDidLoad")
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("VC: viewDidAppear")
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        print("VC: viewDidDisappear")
    }
}
```

If the user force quits the app (using the app switcher), `deinit` is called.  Then when reopening the app, `viewDidLoad` nor `viewDidAppear` are called.  I don't understand why?  I've tried both with and without storyboards and get the same result.  What am I missing?  I don't understand.

Comment: make demo if possible

Comment: Both are called, 100%. Are you debugging via Xcode? If you force kill the app and observe the log but then manually relaunch the app on the phone then the xcode debugger is no longer attached, the methods are called you just don't see the logs.

Comment: Building on that: Just manually attach the debugger again after force quitting the app and you'll be able to see the logs.

Comment: Wow. OMG. I think you are about right. Just tested further and it looks like it's running just the debugger isn't logging as you say. I've tried re-attaching the debugger but no print statements are being logged.  I followed the instructions at https://useyourloaf.com/blog/connecting-xcode-to-a-running-process/ but is there a way to get the log connected also?